# Cordova does not seem to add android.permission.INTERNET

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, phonegap-build

Hi I'm finding lots of posts about people having to many permissions for their android platform when they use cordova.

I'm missing the INTERNET permission. I can add this manually, but I don't want to do this every single time someone wants to compile an app (The platforms dir is on .gitignore and should not be versioned, so whenever someone takes over the project or w/e it should generate fine).

Currently the manifest adds 2 permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

It should however also add INTERNET, which works fine when I add it manually.

I tried adding
    
in my config.xml, also

But no cigar, I removed the android platform also to see if it was just not being built.

Recently tried using Phonegap Build, causes the same issue, also for Windows Phone. So currently I can only do iOS properly.

Comment: was hoping someone knew more about this, also is an issue on Windows Phone, but not iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It magically started working, I have no clue why it didn't get added before. I did not even update the platforms or w/e.